# What is the intersection of all irrationals?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbb{Q}^c$ denotes the set of all irrationals. Then is the following set non-empty?
$$\cap_{x\in \mathbb{R}}x+\mathbb{Q}^c$$

Note: $x+\mathbb{Q}^c=\{x+t|t\in\mathbb{Q}^c\}$

Comment: if a real number $a$ is in your intersection, then what about $a + \Bbb Q^c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $x \in \bigcap_{t \in \Bbb{R}} t+\Bbb Q^{c} $. Then for $t=x$ we have $x \in  x+\Bbb Q^{c}$. So we conclude that $0$ is an irrational number.